# Come scrivere le particelle pronominali in una lettera molto formale dove 'Lei' è scritto maiuscolo

Tags: orthography

Devo scrivere una lettera molto formale dove userò il Lei maiuscolo, della quale qui sotto c'è un passaggio.

> ...
>
> Sì, nonostante Lei abbia concorso a formare il 40,8%, non **si** sconforti, a breve saranno indette nuove elezioni.
>
> ...

La domanda è: Quel **si**, visto che si riferisce alla persona riferita dal **Lei** con la *L* maiuscola, deve essere scritto **Si** con la *S* maiuscola?

Answer (score 3):

I pronomi allocutivi di cortesia sono:

> Tu, Te, Ti, Ella, Lei, La, Le, Voi, Vi, Loro, Li

Poi vi sono i relativi aggettivi possessivi:

> Tuo, Tua, Tuoi, Tue, Suo, Sua, Suoi, Sue, Vostro, Vostra, Vostri, Vostre, Loro

Questi per convenzione vanno in maiuscolo in documenti molto ufficiali (per esempio nelle comunicazioni tra organi dello Stato). Che io sappia le maiuscole di reverenza alla seconda persona singolare si usano esclusivamente quando ci si rivolge a dèi, dee e simili.

Forme come *Glielo*, *Gliela* e simili sono sconsigliati in quanto mescolano a forme solenni un registro linguistico di rango inferiore.

I pronomi riflessivi invece non sono considerati allocutivi di cortesia e non richiedono la maiuscola.

Comment: Nel senso che *glielo* apparterrebbe a un registro linguistico basso? Scherzi? Diciamo piuttosto che la scrittura formale in cui si scrive *chiederLe* appartiene a un registro linguistico suo proprio che non ha molto a che fare con la lingua comune parlata e scritta.